# I'm getting ArgumentException parameter is not valid sometimes when trying to open/show a new form why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have in `Form1` a `pictureBox1` and a double click event:

```
private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb1_fs = new Picturebox1_Fullscreen();
    pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
    g = last_image_file();
    nf = sf + @"\radar" + g.ToString("D6") + ".gif";
    lf = nf;
    pb1_fs.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    pb1_fs.Show();
    pb1_fs.picturebox1(pictureBox1);
    pb1_fs.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(pb1_fs_FormClosing);
}
```

This should open/show the new form `pb1_fs`

I didn't have problems not so much like now with that before.

The problem is once I double click on the `pictureBox1`, sometimes it happen and sometimes not I'm getting

> ArgumentException parameter is no valid.

And I'm not sure where is the problem is since the line it stop on and throw the exception is on `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace mws
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (IsApplicationAlreadyRunning() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The application is already running");
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }

        static bool IsApplicationAlreadyRunning()
        {
            string proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);

            if (processes.Length > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It stop and show the exception on `}`

Here on the second `}` closing.

```
      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

The exception full message is:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=Parameter is not valid.
>   Source=System.Drawing
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
>   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
>   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

The questions are what causes the exception and where if inside the double click event on form1? Or maybe in the new form pb1_fs constructor? How can I check where the problem is?

I can add here also the constructor code of pb1_fs form but it's a big long.

EDIT:

This is the method picturebox1 in the new form.
In Form1 the line:

```
pb1_fs.picturebox1(pictureBox1);
```

Pass the pictureBox1 from Form1 to the new form so in the new form i can use and display the current image that is in form1 pictureBox1.

```
public PictureBox picturebox1(PictureBox pb1)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = pb1.Image;
    return pictureBox1;
}
```

Comment: I added now try and catch but it didn't stop at the catch it jumped right away to the Program.cs and stop there with the exception. Maybe the problem is in the new form pb1_fs constructor code ? And not in the double click event ?

Comment: Your problem is in Form1's constructor, either your code, or the design file. Put a debug in that.

Comment: Can you explain what is this line: `pb1_fs.picturebox1(pictureBox1);`

Comment: Steve updated my question now explained the use of the line: pb1_fs.picturebox1(pictureBox1); with the method code in the new form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error is but would try moving this line

```
pb1_fs.Show();
```

**after** all other initialization code.

Comment: pb1_fs.Show(); display the new form. If i remove it and make doouble click nothing happen.

Comment: don't remove it, just put it after the other code that touches the pb1_fs variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
public PictureBox picturebox1(PictureBox pb1)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = pb1.Image;
  return pictureBox1;
}
```

I think you need to take a clone of that image, so you're not using one instance of that image in 2 different UI-elements. Replace the code with:

```
public PictureBox picturebox1(PictureBox pb1)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = pb1.Image.Clone();
  return pictureBox1;
}
```

I'd also move the **Show()** method on under:

```
pb1_fs.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(pb1_fs_FormClosing);
```

This line